# Superfish First Level: Maintain Hover Properties

Tags: css, superfish

The problem:
http://themeforward.com/demo2/

When I hover over a menu item and begin to mouse down the sub-menu the parent link (i.e. "Templates") loses the properties attributed to it on-hover.  I would like it to maintain these properties.  I've tried numerous variations to achieve this and have been unable to do so.  I *assume* this is achievable via CSS with Superfish and that I'm simply using the incorrect class.

My css:
http://snippi.com/s/hv7m288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the hover event is attached to the `<a>`, but the submenu is a child of the `<li>`.  So adding a hover to the `<li>` will fix it.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7kYF6/

I changed this

```
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
    color:#868E98!important;
    background:#3C4751
}
```

to this and it worked for me

```
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active, .sf-menu li:hover a {
    color:#868E98!important;
    background:#3C4751
}
```